# curl post command doesnt response

Tags: curl, google-api, google-oauth

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGDn3V-mIOM) tutorial on YouTube getting google tokens

```
curl \ --request POST \ --data "code=[my_code]&client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code” \ https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

pressing enter results in terminal `>`, indicating it needs more input I guess

What do I need to add/ edit to get the access/refresh tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i use I hope it helps.  The basic diffrence is that you should use `&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` for your redirect uri it will cause the system to return the code back to whatever ip address and file called it.

```
# Client id from Google Developer console
# Client Secret from Google Developer console
# Scope this is a space seprated list of the scopes of access you are requesting.

# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Code ripped from [GoogleAuthenticationCurl.sh](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)

Answer (score 0):

Closing quotation and opening quotation do not match, so command line is still expecting closing quotation.

Use below command

```
curl \ --request POST \ --data "code=[my_code]&client_id=[my_client_id]&client_secret=[my_client_secret]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code" \ https://account
s.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

`"` cant be used with `”`